Should I include others' answers in my answer?
Let's say I look at a question that already has some comments containing suggestions and a couple of answers. And while I think the answers have useful information, I still think more should be said. I could:

Write my own answer that says something like, "in addition to what Dick and Jane have said, you should also do this..."
Write a complete answer, including the information already posted, along with my additional information.

My feeling is that we should be kind to future visitors, so #2. Nobody wants to scroll through 10 answers to find the 3 that, combined, are a good answer. Instead, create one answer to rule them all. But I'm open to contrary views, especially if they represent the SO consensus.
If I do #2, I feel the need to give credit where credit is due. Should I:

Include references in my answer to the comments/answers that I drew from,
Include a comment on my own answer with those references.
Include comments on the posts I drew from.

I shy away from #1. Again, a future visitor doesn't care where the information came from, and a lot of "I want to thank everybody who made this possible" wastes their time. (Posting links to external sources is still valuable, especially if those links dive into more detail and/or are more authoratative.) #3 can effectively hide the citations. I lean to #2.
And finally, should I upvote the answers/comments that I drew from? I could see two ways of thinking of it:

Yes, do it. The answers, while incomplete, were valuable, and the posters invested their time to try to make the world a better place. Reward them.
No, don't. The voting system is not intended to be a reward to the poster; it's intended to tell future visitors which answers are the best. Voting for incomplete answers when a more complete answer is available hinders future visitors from finding the best answer.

I'm leaning towards #2, but let's face it: gamification was also a goal of SO. No matter how much we try to respect future visitors, the simple truth is that votes ARE a form of reward. If I didn't get any feedback for my work, I would probably stop doing it. If there were a "tip jar" that I could give some of my points to the other answerers, I would do it, so long as it is clear why I'm doing it.
On the other hand, sometimes I already knew the information in those other answers and intended to give it. I.e. it wasn't copied at all, I independently knew it. I probably wouldn't tip incomplete answers in that case.
Or am I just over-thinking this?

How do you plagiarise a suggestion? Someone stating, in the comments, "Have you considered trying to foo the bar" doesn't mean that if someone (else) then answers explaining how to foo the bar is committing plagiarism.

All content on SO (including comments) is released under a CC BY-SA license. When you incorporate a comment into your answer. You have to state the author of the comment. Something like "As XYZ said, ..." should be enough.

It is entirely possible to have the same idea as a commenter independently. In that case I very likely wouldn't add noise to my answer by even mentioning the commenter. I'd just write the answer and maybe flag the comment as "no longer needed"

Having each individual contribution voted on is a pro, not a con. If you feel you can add to the body of work on a post then by all means do so, but there is no need to be concerned with the already voted sections.

I shy away from #1. Again, a future visitor doesn't care where the information came from. Not everything must cater to a future visitor. In particular, ethical obligations trump expediency for future visitors. I think prominently mentioning the source of your content up front is the best way to properly attribute it. There are other ways, of course. A deletable comment doesn't seem adequate to me.

@TravisJ So you're voting for: 1. Write my own answer that says something like, "in addition to what Dick and Jane have said, you should also do this..." I.e. let Dick and Jane's content be voted on, and my addition also voted? And leave it to a future reader to look for all useful content, answer by answer?

what do you mean by "include a comment on"? do you mean "add/post a comment on"?

@StreveFord - Yes, leave it to the weighted history of every previous visitor to guide the future reader.

@starball Yes, I mean add a comment to my own answer containing attributions of other answers I drew from. It's assuming I decided to create an aggregate answer including information from one or more existing answers plus my own contribution. And I wanted to give credit for the parts that weren't my original work. The alternative would be to not recap other answers, and only give my "value add" in my answer. The "In addition to what Dick and Jane said, do this..." choice, which seems to be the majority position of comments so far.

"gamification was also a goal of SO" -- gamification was a strategy, not a goal. "the simple truth is that votes ARE a form of reward" -- I presume that you mean that upvotes are a form of reward, but the more important role of votes is to provide some index of quality for posted material.

I'm personally a proponent of #2 (new answer post). As long as I feel that my addition warrants a new answer post (and that's usually a judgement call, but I think I'm a bit more on the lenient side).
I wouldn't do #1, and I when I see other people do it (usually new users who aren't very familiar with this platform and how we roll), my reaction is :/ . I think your line of thinking is better aligned to how this platform works / is supposed to work.

If I do #2, I feel the need to give credit where credit is due. Should I:

Include references in my answer to the comments/answers that I drew from,
Post a comment on my own answer with those references.
Include comments on the posts I drew from.


I sometimes do 1. 2 also works I think. Up to you. I wouldn't do 3, unless I see something in existing answers that I want to give constructive feedback on- Ex. I feel compelled to call out something that I think is wrong. If I do that, then it's another judgement call whether I want in that comment to point out that I have a "competing" answer post. If I'm calling out something I think is wrong, then I'd probably only do that if I felt it was quite egregious (I try to have some self-control not to come off as self-promoting in those cases).

And finally, should I upvote the answers/comments that I drew from? I could see two ways of thinking of it [...]

This is up to you.
